# Why is the sum of probability is not equal to 1 in a geometric distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A company has five employees on its health insurance plan. Each year, each employee independently has an 80% probability of no hospital admissions. If an employee requires one or more hospital admissions, the number of admissions is modeled by a geometric distribution with a mean of 1.50. The numbers of hospital admissions of different employees are mutually independent.

Each hospital admission costs 20,000.

Calculate the probability that the company’s total hospital costs in a year are less than 50,000.

The probability of each employee has at least one hospital admissions is (0.2*1)/(1 - 2/3) = 0.6 instead of 0.2. Why is that?

Comment: How exactly do you arrive at $.6$?  I don't follow.

Comment: As the cost is less than $50 000$, we can have either $0, 1$ or $2$ employees sick.

Comment: The probability that each employee has at least 1 hospital admission is $1 - (4/5)^5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the employee has a hospital admission, the number of admissions is geometrically distributed with mean $\frac32$. That is the probability of exactly $k$ admissions is $p(1-p)^{k-1},\ k=1,2,\dots$ and the mean is $\frac1p$ so $p=\frac23.$  However, these probabilities are conditional probabilities, contingent on the employee's having had at least one admission (probability $.2$.)  Therefore the probability $p_k$ that an employee has exactly $k$ admissions is $$p_k=\cases{.8,&$k=0$\\.4\cdot3^{-k},&$k>0$}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it now. ty.